# What is the difference between UML Domain Model and Context Diagram

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Firstly, I'm still quite new to UML; but, highly interested and am attempting to learn as much about it as I can.

With that said, I’m in a situation where I’m directed to assemble a ‘Context Diagram’. I feel as though I understand the concept of what a context diagram is and how to create one, so I think I’m ok there. Basically it is identifying the system and the components or actors it will interact with. It applies the focus on the system, and not the actors. Kind of like a Use case diagram, but not focusing on the actors. If I’m wrong, please tell me.

I read somewhere that Context Diagrams are not actually part of UML. I also read, somewhere, that, if you use a Context Diagram, it falls into the Component side of things. When I read about Domain models, it seems like it should be there.

For my current situation, I know a simple answer is to simply create the diagram and move on, as that is all that is required. But, for my interest to better understand and leverage UML, I know there is a right way and a wrong way. If I were in a case of a bigger project, what would be the right way?

Now here is where my question begins. I’m using Enterprise Architect, create my project, and start to create a model. Does it belong in a Domain Model or Component Model? What is the difference between these two? Or even more. As it is an aide to help identify requirements, should it go there? Or does is just simply depend on what and how I want to convey it?

Comment: Neither **Context Diagram** nor **Domain Diagram** are terms defined in UML. If you use them please indicate which method you are using them from, and maybe add the definition as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Domain Model is where you standardize the vocabulary that everyone on the project will use to communicate in a consistent manner. The development team are experts at software development, but they may not have any experience in the domain (e.g. banking, air traffic control, healthcare) in which they are being asked to work. So you get domain experts and modelling experts together to build a model that describes the domain, answering important questions like "how are account fees calculated?" and "how does a pilot know what route to follow?" and then this model is then passed to the development team to provide them with the important domain knowledge that they will need. I would use UML class diagrams to create a domain model.

A Context Diagram shows the system being modeled in relationship to external systems. It could show data flowing in from and out to external systems, modeled by a data flow diagram (not part of UML). It could show behavioral interactions between the system and external "actors", modeled by a UML use case diagram. It could show the system's physical connections to other systems, modeled by a SysML block diagram. Whichever you choose, it will be on page 1 of your design document, so choose wisely!

Comment: This helps a lot in understanding where, why and how they apply. Your explanation of the Domain model was extremely helpful. I had some reasonable understanding of Domain at a very high level; however, this description filled in many blanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You (can) create context diagram by making any element composite. Then drag the element itself onto that diagram as link (not instance!) and highlight it by making the border a bit thicker. Finally insert related elements from the context menu (differs from EA version to version). Layout the diagram and now you have your element in the context.

A domain model is usually a class diagram showing the (business) domain on a higher abstraction level.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort, I'm comfortable with the drawing aspects. Its understanding how some of the domains, as per their names, and how they relate to the objective and their respective diagrams. The drawing is easy. It's seems to be the inter-connectivity between all various models, diagrams and documents and how they should be organized and tied together that I struggle with the most

Comment: Well, then it's probably not a question to be asked at StackOverflow. Anyhow: A context diagram focuses on single elements and shows how they relate to other elements. It is a single diagram. A domain model in contrast is (what it says) a model - also a set of diagrams. In a domain model you abstract the domain in question to a number of classes representing the domain objects. A domain model helps understanding the whole. A context diagram helps understanding the individual element.

Comment: /OT @ThomasKilian I've been telling you, you'll quickly going to gain rep here. Did I promise to much? Hope you enjoy it, cya!

Comment: Yep. It's really fun :-) TY

Answer (score 2):

As you have said, Context Diagrams *per se* are not part of the UML spec.  There are plenty of ways to do a context diagram, but the UML way is to use a Use Case diagram, with or without supporting narratives and scenarios.  Start with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_context_diagram), which is a broad overview of different types of Context Diagrams.  Then, investigate use case diagrams, use case narratives, and activity diagrams.  If you need to go into more detail than a use case narrative can easily do, get into use case scenarios and sequence diagrams.  [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+case+narrative+sample&rlz=1C1KMZB_enMX606US606&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=963&tbm=isch&imgil=qEHhtuLcFkm8YM%253A%253BBct475FVhrdrxM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.cs.colorado.edu%25252F~kena%25252Fclasses%25252F6448%25252Fs05%25252Freference%25252Fusecases%25252Fexamples.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=qEHhtuLcFkm8YM%253A%252CBct475FVhrdrxM%252C_&usg=__Q_aKHj9-tKnrZ-1VM0GBLq3j9a8%3D&ved=0CCsQyjc&ei=IK-AVOHnLIH0iAL3gIHoBw#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=OTOMl07UYTebRM%253A%3BFp5pc998uLMZIM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.jot.fm%252Fissues%252Fissue_2005_08%252Farticle2%252Fimages%252Ffigure2.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.jot.fm%252Fissues%252Fissue_2005_08%252Farticle2%252F%3B721%3B953) is a pretty good use case narrative template (feel free to leave out sections such as "scope and level" if they are more than you need, and consider adding information about what triggers the use case and where you go when you finish it--these two are required for scenarios if you go that far).

Keep in mind that use case narratives and use case scenarios are often confused.  (Some people will say that I am the confused one; I will invite you to judge the matter for yourself.)  A narrative is an explanation of an entire (single) use case, and may be supported with an activity diagram.  A scenario is an explanation of a single path through a single use case, and may be supported with a sequence diagram.

For example, a use case will generally have a basic flow of events, along with a number of alternate flows.  The narrative describes the entire process.  The basic flow and each alternate flow would each be a separate use case scenario.

I suspect that it's unlikely that you will have to get down to the level of use case scenarios.  You will probably want to put a use case diagram together, and possibly prepare narratives and activity diagrams for each of the use cases in the diagram.

Comment: Reading your response, I perceive a tone of recommendation to pursue Use Case, instead of Context. I think I agree from the perspective that Context diagrams aren’t part of the UML and who am I to deviate while I’m still in the infancy of trying to learn it. With that said, I have no choice on this one, because, as I stated earlier, I have been directed to generate a ‘Context Diagram’. I’m stuck with it here. So I’ll make the best of it and learn what I can.

Comment: Cont.

Beyond that, I respect what you have provided. I learned more from what you gave me than I received through my scattered efforts to understand over the past 2-3 years. Your hierarchical breakdown helps me to understand better than anything I’ve found so far. I can’t find that anywhere. I find here’s a diagram, what it’s for, how to make it, blah blah. 1 diagram doesn’t cut it. I can’t find a breakdown of how they should tie together for the big picture. You may not have made me a UML expert, but you have certainly improved my toolbox for extending use cases and make them more useful.

Comment: If you were directed to create a Context Diagram you better asked the person that did so what it should be. There is no context diagram defined in UML.

Comment: Lee, go to the first link I provided and have a look at the bottom bullet point in the list of types of context diagrams. You will notice that it refers to the UML use case diagram as one of several types of context diagrams. Context diagram is a broad definition of a diagram that maps out the problem domain.  Use case diagrams are used for this purpose.  It's just a matter of semantics really.  Your "use case instead of context" is simply a misunderstanding of this point.  A use case diagram IS a context diagram; one of many.

Comment: @BobRodes Many thanks. That makes perfect sense and is, pretty much, how I have taken it. After many searches and readings, I've collected that Use Cases and Context Diagrams much alike. Use Cases focusing on users and Context focusing on systems.

Comment: Again, you don't seem to quite get it, Lee.  Use Cases focus on systems as well, how systems are used.  Those cute little actor stick figures don't change that.  Let me try to explain "a use case diagram IS a context diagram" in another way: ALL use case diagrams are context diagrams.  Not all context diagrams are use case diagrams.  Think of it this way.  All Marlboros are cigarettes.  Not all cigarettes are Marlboros.